# AS3 Removechild Addchild issue/error

Tags: actionscript-3, bitmap, bitmapdata, removechild, addchild

I have been looking for an answer for hours:

My program:

Step I) When I click on a button, it displays a bitmap through addchild;
Step II) When I click on another button, it should remove the bitmap through removechild;

Step I) works perfectly but step II) doesn't work.

You'll find below some parts of my code:

First, I declare:

```
public var ajoutcarte4:MovieClip;
```

Secondly, In the main function I wrote:

```
var ajoutcarte4:Bitmap = new Bitmap();
```

Then, in a sub function triggered by the first button, I add the Bitmap to the stage (fl_bitmap is a function returning a Bitmap item):

```
ajoutcarte4 = fl_bitmap(couleur4+figure4);
ajoutcarte4.x=445;
ajoutcarte4.y=370;
addChild(ajoutcarte4);
```

So far so good but when I want to remove the child through another sub function triggered by a second button:

```
removeChild(ajoutcarte4);
```

It doesn't work because ajoutecarte4 is apparently null... Error 2007 when i get red of my condition...

Answer (score 1):

change this

```
public var ajoutcarte4:MovieClip;
```

to

```
public var ajoutcarte4:Bitmap;
```

Then take out this line completely

```
var ajoutcarte4:Bitmap = new Bitmap();
```

And lastely

```
// add this like with this code
ajoutcarte4 = new bitMap()
ajoutcarte4 = fl_bitmap(couleur4+figure4);
ajoutcarte4.x=445;
ajoutcarte4.y=370;
addChild(ajoutcarte4);
```

Answer (score 0):

You've declared a **field** ajoutcarte4 of type MovieClip, but then in your function, you declare a **local variable** ajoutcarte4 of type Bitmap, which is then added to the stage.

In the second function, you try to remove the **field** MovieClip, which has never been instantiated - and thus produces the error.

Change your declaration to this:

```
public var ajoutcarte4:Bitmap;
```

and call:

```
ajoutcarte4 = new Bitmap();
```

(without the `var`).  Then it all should work correctly.